# Return only first item from a related group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a block of data like this:

```
RW |  PK   A    B    C    D
============================
1  |  1    aa   123  x    99
2  |  2    aa   234  v    98
3  |  3    bb   321  z    11
4  |  4    bb   210  w    91
5  |  5    cc   456  y    55
```

How can I grab just the first item of each set (ID'd by column A), like so?

```
RW |  A    B    C    D
=======================
1  |  aa   123  x    99
2  |  bb   321  z    11
3  |  cc   456  y    55
```

I can `GROUP BY` or use `DISTINCT` but that's very inefficient with what I'm looking at, while running a straight list takes less than 100msecs. The two aforementioned options also may produce more than once instance of an item in column A, since the related values may differ.

In other words,

```
SELECT MYTABLE.A, MYTABLE.D, MYTABLE.D, MYTABLE.D 
FROM MYTABLE
```

is very fast (less than a second), while

```
SELECT MYTABLE.A, MYTABLE.D, MYTABLE.D, MYTABLE.D 
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY MYTABLE.A, MYTABLE.D, MYTABLE.D, MYTABLE.D
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT MYTABLE.A, MYTABLE.D, MYTABLE.D, MYTABLE.D 
FROM MYTABLE
```

takes a much longer amount of time (minutes, but I have not let it complete).

I need no aggregate functions (`COUNT`, `SUM`, etc.), just a listing, once per item. The number of occurrences per value in column A vary, so I can't just grab every *x* row.

**Why don't I just run the list and use Excel or something like that to sort?** I'm looking at a few million records to be returned, and I am not able to process so many records using any software that I am familiar with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like

```
SELECT pk,
       a,
       b,
       c,
       d
  FROM( SELECT pk,
               a,
               b,
               c,
               d,
               row_number() over (partition by a order by pk asc) rnk
          FROM your_table )
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: This looks like it will return the right results, but this still takes a significant amount of time to run. I may be asking for too much, but is there any faster method?

Comment: @Gaffi - What does "a significant amount of time" mean?  Presumably, Oracle is going to have to do a full table scan of the table (or a full scan of a covering index depending on the columns you select) and there will be some sorting.  If the query is going to return millions of rows, that implies the table has tens of millions of rows so a table scan isn't likely to be instantaneous.  On the other hand, if the table is a few GB in size, it shouldn't take hours for the query to run unless you've got serious I/O issues.

Comment: I mean 'significant' in that the direct pull of all records is less than a second, but the grouping/sorting takes minutes. I am running the query now, and I don't know how long it will take overall, but I will update again when it's done.

Comment: @Gaffi - Are you sure that it takes a second to return all million rows?  That seems unlikely particularly if you are running this on a machine other than the database server.  Most GUIs will display the first N rows that are returned relatively quickly while the database is still processing the query.  When you introduce a sort, however, Oracle often can't return the first row until it has read the last row from the table because it can't be sure that the last row isn't going to change the sort order.  You need to compare the time required to retrieve the last row not the first row.

Comment: It took about 9 minutes, so that's not wholly unreasonable. If I have to live with the wait, that is ok, I would just rather have as small as possible.

Comment: To clarify, yes, only the first 500 are returned in that time. Exporting/loading more results does take more time, but still the whole export would be done in less than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this too..

```
select * from table where rowid in (select min(rowid) from table group by a);
```

Comment: `try this` is not a proper answer. Post a comment instead.